# The print statement won't let me input stuff

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

***What i want to do:***

I want to program kind of an messenger between a server and multiple clients in python. I got an server running with the sockets library and i can get the input of a user and send it back to a user. My problem here is, that i want to be able to type, while it's printing out the new messages.

***My problem:***

When i print out the new messages, i can't type anything in the console and when i got an simple gui with tkinter programmed, it just straightup doesn't respond and crashes. I know the problem is somewhere in the `get_message` function in my client.py.

***My code:***

Yes i know it's not the best and efficient way possible, but it works for me.

Any help is helpful.

**server.py**

```
import socket
import threading
import pickle


HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
update_message_char = "update_messages_char"
SERVER = "0.0.0.0"  # it's using my virtualbox host-only adapter, which i don't want:
#  socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!disconnect"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

usernames = {}
author = []
messages = []
forbidden_chars = ["message_update", "update_messages_char"]


def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"New Connection: {addr} connected\n")
    username_received = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
    if addr not in usernames.keys():
        if username_received:
            username_received = int(username_received)
            username = conn.recv(username_received).decode(FORMAT)
            usernames[addr] = username
            print(f"{addr} has got the username {username}")

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_length:
            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
            print(f"{usernames[addr]} said: {msg}")
            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False
            elif msg == update_message_char:
                author_list = pickle.dumps(author)
                message_list = pickle.dumps(messages)
                conn.send(author_list)
                conn.send(message_list)
            elif msg not in forbidden_chars:
                messages.append(msg)
                author.append(usernames[addr])

    conn.close()
    print(f"Connection to {usernames[addr]} closed")


def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"Active Connections {threading.activeCount() -1}")


print(f"Server is starting on port {PORT}")
start()
```

**client.py:**

```
import socket
import time
import pickle
import threading
import tkinter as tk

HEIGHT = 800
WIDTH = 1200


update_message_char = "update_messages_char"
HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!disconnect"
SERVER = "192.168.0.18"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
counter = 0

messages = []
author = []

old_messages = []
old_authors = []

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)


def send(msg):
    if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
        disconnect()
    elif msg == "update_message":
        thread = threading.Thread(target=get_messages())
        thread.start()
    else:
        message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
        msg_length = len(message)
        send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
        send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
        client.send(send_length)
        client.send(message)


def disconnect():
    print("You will be disconnected from the server and the program will close")
    message = f"{DISCONNECT_MESSAGE}".encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
    client.send(send_length)
    client.send(message)
    exit()


def setup_username():
    username = input("Please type in your username: ")
    username = username.encode(FORMAT)
    username_length = len(username)
    send_length = str(username_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
    client.send(send_length)
    client.send(username)


def get_messages():
    global counter
    send(update_message_char)
    author_list = pickle.loads(client.recv(2048))
    message_list = pickle.loads(client.recv(2048))
    if counter == 0:
        for i in author_list:
            author.append(i)
        for i in message_list:
            messages.append(i)
        counter += 1
    elif counter == 1:
        for i in author:
            old_authors.append(i)
        for i in messages:
            old_messages.append(i)
        for i in author:
            author.remove(i)
        for i in messages:
            messages.remove(i)
        for i in author_list:
            author.append(i)
        for i in message_list:
            messages.append(i)
    list1 = set(messages)
    list2 = set(old_messages)
    list3 = list1.difference(list2)
    time.sleep(4)
    get_messages()


def gui():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Messaging service lol")

    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
    canvas.pack()

    frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="black", bd=5)
    frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=0.1, relx=0.5, rely=0.0001, anchor="n")

    button = tk.Button(root, text="Send", bg="#041982", fg="black", font=40, command=lambda: send(entry.get()))
    button.place(relx=0.8, rely=0.0001, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.1)

    c1 = tk.Button(frame, text="Exit", bg="#041982", font=20, command=disconnect)
    c1.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.0001, relwidth=0.1, relheight=0.3)

    entry = tk.Entry(frame, bg="#404040")
    entry.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.4, relwidth=0.25, relheight=0.4)

    lower_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="black")
    lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=1, relheight=0.9, anchor="n")

    label = tk.Label(lower_frame, bg="black", fg="red", anchor="nw", justify="left", font=20)
    label.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx=0.1, rely=0.1)

    root.mainloop()


setup_username()
print(f"You are connected to the server!\nIf you want to disconnect, simply type {DISCONNECT_MESSAGE}")

thread = threading.Thread(target=gui)
thread.start()
```

Comment: It's a little difficult for me to figure out the program. A few questions: (1) why do you run the GUI in a separate thread? At least on my Mac, it causes the client to crash immediately. (2) there's a neverending recursion in get-messages. Is that the purpose? (3) old-messages and messages are defined globally, but not treated as such in get_messages. Is that the purpose?

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking at my code. It's a bit messy, with global varibles and stuff as you mentioned.I wanted to have like a constant message updater(in the get_messages func) and like get the difference of the 2 lists and print the difference(thats why the lists are there). I wanted to have the gui in a thread as i thought, that that would fix my problem of not being able to write in the console, while the get_messages func runs. I moved on from that code, i found a workaround to my problem (instead of storing the messages in lists, i just send them to each user).